# How let netty know that the idle connection is being timed out by NLB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, netty, nlb

I am using Netty server behind the NLB(network load balancer). I am maintaining the total number of connections counter. 
NLBs have an idle timeout of 350 seconds. When connections expire through idle timeout, NLBs terminate the connections silently.
How can I let netty know that the connection has been timed out?

I found that when connections expire through idle timeout, the NLB would notify the client that the connection has been terminated by sending it a RST packet, though  ELBs sends a FIN packet to each connected party.
In case of ELB it is working perfectly fine.
Netty version I am using: 5.0.0.Alpha2

How can I let netty know and maintain a proper counter for the number of connections?

Comment: So NLB sends nothing to the server on timeout?  What if the server tries to send traffic to the (no longer connected) client after that?  I would hope for at least an RST toward the server in that case, if nothing else.

Comment: As per NLB documentation 
`If a client sends data after the idle timeout period elapses, it receives a TCP RST packet to indicate that the connection is no longer valid.`

Comment: And from this link as well [https://medium.com/tenable-techblog/lessons-from-aws-nlb-timeouts-5028a8f65dda]
`Upon idle timeout, the ELB sent FIN packets to the client and its targets. On the other hand, the NLB only sent RST packets to its clients when it received traffic following idle timeout.`